# Implementing Twitter Into Website Using API

Tags: jquery, twitter, api, embed

I used to use a JQuery plugin called Seaofclouds on my websites to embed the latest 5 or 10 tweets into my footer but since 1.1 came out this function is not available any more - Is there an updated version of this JQuery that will work with API 1.1?

I have the keys and AUTH scripts on my server but I'm unsure of how they should be used properly to embed the tweet.

Answer (score 1):

They explain workarounds [here](https://github.com/seaofclouds/tweet/issues/264).

There are of course many alternatives to Seaofclouds to achieve your latest tweets though of course.

Comment: Thanks Geoff, That looks great - I'll take a closer look at that today (As soon as I've sorted my bookmarking problem) - Thanks again